# Tags not saving in Profiles

Tags: profile, permissions, tags

USAGE:  I've created a Profile that includes the global Tagset.  I'm using it to designate a Region Tag for all Contacts as we roll out a directory.  The Tags have values such as "Northeast", "Northwest", etc.

[image: My set of Tags]

PROBLEM:  When a user saves their information using the Profile, the Tags selected are not saved in CiviCRM and thus the Tags selected are not shown also in their confirmation.

BACKGROUND

1. I have tested that I can save Tags to a Contact within CiviCRM
   through the backend.  All other fields are being saved correctly.
2. Using CiviCRM 4.7.30, WordPress 4.9.4
3. I have reviewed my WordPress permissions regarding 'tags', but willing to recheck or check others.

Comment: Have you compared behaviour to what is happening on one of the demo sites?

Comment: No, but I can.  What's the URL and info on accounts to use?

Comment: eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ demo // demo - but that is something you could have found out easily yourself i think - hmm for you are WP. https://civicrm.org/demo - at bottom of page

Comment: Was able to repeat the problem on the demo site, http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.  Added a children off the existing 'Company' tag and used the 'Create' mode to see if it would save.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a Tag set as a Custom Field for Contacts. I was then able to save the selections made by a user through a Profile. This solution is sufficient for my application.

Answer (score 0):

This use case may be better suited to setting up contact classifications using groups rather than tags for a few reasons https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/#groups-vs-tags